# context-menu button fires once in Excel Add-In

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

My context-menu button fires only once.
btn object dies on startup. How can I fix it?

How can I fix calling object so early?

```
public partial class ThisAddIn
{
    private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {                        
        PicPaste btn = new PicPaste(this.Application);}
```

---

```
class PicPaste
{
    private Excel.Application application;
    private Office.CommandBarButton   picpasteMenuItem;
    public PicPaste(Excel.Application app)
    {
        application = app;
        CreatePicpasteBtn();
    }

    public  void CreatePicpasteBtn()
    {
        Office.MsoControlType contextMenuItem = Office.MsoControlType.msoControlButton;
        Office.CommandBar commandBarCell = application.CommandBars["Cell"];
        picpasteMenuItem = commandBarCell.Controls.Add(contextMenuItem, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, 5, true) 
            as Office.CommandBarButton;

        if (picpasteMenuItem != null)
        {
            picpasteMenuItem.Style = Office.MsoButtonStyle.msoButtonCaption;
            picpasteMenuItem.Caption = "Вставить изображение в коммент";
            picpasteMenuItem.Click += new Office._CommandBarButtonEvents_ClickEventHandler(
                PicPasteMenuItemClick);
        }
    }

    private static void PicPasteMenuItemClick(Office.CommandBarButton Ctrl, ref bool CancelDefault)
    {
       ...some code here

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're declaring and instantiating the object `PicPaste btn = new PicPaste(this.Application);` in a method/event. That means it will be scoped to this procedure; it goes out of scope when the procedure finishes and will eventually be garbage collected.

You need to *declare* any objects that should exist for the life-time of your add-in at the *class level* - outside any procedure. Then they'll stay in-scope until your add-in is unloaded.

So, for example:

```
public partial class ThisAddIn
{
  PicPaste btn = null;
  private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
  {                        
    btn = new PicPaste(this.Application);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the scope of the `PicPaste` instance is limited someway. But the approach is right - to keep the source object defined at the class level to prevent it from swiping from the heap by the GC. Try to use a list of controls which will be stored at the add-in class level, or something like that:

```
PicPaste btn = null;
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{                        
    btn = new PicPaste(this.Application);
}
```